# Dropbox Python SDK , unable to download or list files

Tags: python, dropbox-sdk

We are planning to use Dropbox to get some csv files transfered from client location. This csv files need to be processed by a data engineering pipeline. We are using python to process this. As a first step , we need to download the file from dropbox to the local file folder. I have created an app using Dropbox App Console as Scoped App first. In the Python program we need to get an API Access token. And from the scopped App , I was not able to generate the Access token as I was getting error stating that " You need to be a Team administrator to generate the token". This was misleading as this was a single account  i created for testing it out and no teams are present. I tried with another method which is using the user id  and secret to prompt for an access token

here is the code :

```
class DropboxFolderCreation:
    """ 
    This class is responsible for creating empty directories in  dropbox account. 
    """
    def __init__(self):
        # define your dropbox app key below
        self.app_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        # define your dropbox app secret key below
        self.app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        # define your CSV file path below
        self.csv_path = 'example.csv'
    def login_dropbox(self):
        """
         Authorise Dropbox using OAuth 2.0
         Follow instructions and authorise your Dropbox account.
         """
        APP_KEY = self.app_key
        APP_SECRET = self.app_secret
        auth_flow = dropbox.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
        authorize_url = auth_flow.start()
        print ("1. Go to: " + authorize_url)
        print ("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).")
        print ("3. Copy the authorization code.")
        auth_code = input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()
        try: 
            oauth_result = auth_flow.finish(auth_code)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: %s" % (e,))
        return oauth_result
        
    def read_csv(self,dbx):
        """
         read .csv file and extract directory names
         """
        """wb = open_workbook(self.csv_path).sheet_by_index(0)
        directory_list = []
         # if csv file contains data from row 2 then set start_rowx = 1
         # else set it to 0 as below
         # first argument is set to 0 since we want to read column 1 of csv
        csv_data = wb.col_values(0, start_rowx = 0)"""
        #dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(<access_token>)

        metadata, f = dbx.files_download(self.csv_path)
        print(metadata)
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f.content.decode().splitlines(), delimiter=',')
        with open(metadata) as file:
            line_count = 0
            for row in csv_reader:
                if line_count == 0:
                    print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
                    line_count += 1
                else:
                    print(row)
                    line_count += 1

            print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')


        return csv_data
    
    def create_dirs_on_dropbox(self):
        """
         Create empty directories in Dropbox account using API v2
         """
        
        token = self.login_dropbox()
        dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(token.access_token)
        dirs = self.read_csv(dbx)
        csv_data = self.read_csv(dbx)
        if csv_data:
            #doing something here 
             print("Successfully download  file from  your dropbox account ")
        else:
            print("could not read data from csv file")
```

And when executing the below :

```
dbx_instance = DropboxFolderCreation()
dbx_instance.create_dirs_on_dropbox()

1. Go to: https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=a9hg3hhu85613yv
2. Click "Allow" (you might have to log in first).
3. Copy the authorization code.
Enter the authorization code here: dTuX5n5_iV0AAAAAAAAAKX5Rrskr-ZCroPMjuSK2qMo
```

Connection to Dropbox is successful , but getting error while trying to access the file

error as :

```
ValidationError: 'ListPriceChanges.csv' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*|id:.*)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'
```

-I suspected this error is coming because I am not able to read the folder list which I verified using this

```
response = dbx.files_list_folder(path="")
print(response)
```

which returns an empty list.

So My problem is how to generate the access token for the scoped App . Do we have any simple way to connect and download the files ?

Answer (score 0):

We have similar issues . When you use scope application, do not select any scope related to teams ,

from the App console, select your application, Click on the scoped App, and deselect everything under the team scope

[image]

you can come back and generate the access token now.

Once you have access token for your scoped App, then it is pretty straight forward

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("access token")

with open("example.csv", "wb") as f:
    metadata, res = dbx.files_download(path="/example.csv")
    f.write(res.content)
```

The above code will download the example.csv from the root folder . If you have the file under any folder say test then in the path you need to specify /test/example.csv

Comment: Thank you much , After unchecking the team scope, I created the access token , and able to download the file